# Multiple lua_calls exiting and generating a "C stack overflow"

Tags: c++, lua

I'm working in a multi-process environment using C++ with some Lua bindings, using Lua functions to manage some aspects of the processes, with a single shared Lua context among them.

The general form I'm using is by hooking certain events, triggering Lua functions which in turn reach C++ code.

I push two arguments which are process-related on the stack, and then issue

```
lua_call(L, 2, 0);
```

The problem is that some specific `lua_call` reach a kill function (intended behavior), but since the `lua_call` doesn't return, the stack doesn't get freed. After about 200 such calls, Lua panics due to a C stack overflow.

I've printed the Lua stack at each hook and I can see it grow. I've tried using `lua_pop(L, 2)` (stack grows by 2 each time), `lua_settop(L, 0)` after Lua consumes the arguments and issues the callback, just before killing the process, but to no avail.

I can't call `lua_close(L)` because that would destroy the context which is shared among processes, and would result in accessing a NULL context by other processes.

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to not share your Lua context between processes. (Actually, I'm surprised that works)

Comment: You need to use some sort of locks, if you run two threads through a lua VM at once then you are getting undefined behavior.

Comment: Why don't the lua calls return? It is consistent with the spec that you will be leaking stack entries if you do this. When you call "lua_call" with some arguments, the arguments below the function call will be protected by lua, and it will virtually move the stack frame in order to support the call. the "original" stack only becomes accesible when you return from the function. You must eventually return from the call or those entries are leaked forever AFAIK.

Comment: @ChrisBeck: Thank you for your insightful comment! From what I understand, at any given point, even though I can view any stack frame, I can only free the current stackframe. The reason the call does not return is because the process who made the call has been killed as a result of the call (again, this is the desired behavior). Another option I can try is to schedule the process kill after the call returns somehow.

Comment: @vladimird: You could use a separate Lua thread for each of your processes. They have independent stacks and are subject to garbage collection when you don't need them anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround is instead of outright killing the process issuing the `lua_call`, I set a flag and kill it only after the call returns, ensuring no leftover stack frames.

Thanks again to Chris Beck for his insightful comment on how the Lua stack works.